# Removing pemalinks with date structure on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog and I´ve been working a little bit on my SEO. I passed my site through 
http://www.siteliner.com/

and found that I have some "duplicated" content, which are the date links from some posts I´ve made.

I have my permalinks setting as follows

[image]

I don´t understand why those links still appear on my website since I just want them to be accesed by post name.

Here are the results of siteliner:

[image]

as you can see there are some posts with the year and month of publication that take me exactly to the same place as the post name.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date links you see aren't actually extraneous permalinks to your posts. They're part of the built-in Wordpress archives. Pages with the format /year, /year/month, and /year/month/day are being created for every time period you have posts.

If you want to disable them, one easy option is with the [Wordpress SEO Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) by Joost de Valk. You can also add this to a plugin to redirect any requests for non-admin or regular pages:

```
function wpa_parse_query( $query ){
    if( !is_admin() && !$query->is_page ) wp_redirect( home_url() );
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpa_parse_query' );
```

Or add manual redirects to your .htaccess.

(Taken from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95920/how-do-i-remove-unwanted-pages-like-archive-search-etc/)).